# POST request to search an object with multiple values on WEBUI

Tags: python

Trying to build a POST request to get the data from a website. In POST request, I need to send multiple values of same parameter and each value is ended by CRLF (%0D%0A) encoding. It seems the request being handled by web server is on Windows OS.

Data in POST from chrome Inspect:

```
URL: http://somerandomeurl/query.php
ServerNames = Server1%0D%0AServer2%0D%0AServer3%0D%0AServer4
reportview = Full
```

I was trying to use requests library with no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? The code I mean

Comment: Here is the basic effort I've made :   
`url='http://somerandomeurl/query.php'  
payload = {'Servernames':'Server1\r\nServer2'&'reportview':'Full'}  
r = requests.post(url,data=payload)  
print (r.text)  
`
I've tried using both types of CRLF encodings \r\n & %0D%0A but query hangs